# Why STS Run As... > Run on server make tomcat server module automatically?

Tags: tomcat

Why STS Run As... > Run on server make tomcat server module automatically?

I click that button to publish to tomcat server, it keep automatically publish to Path "/".

[tomcat Web Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIjlf.png)

I want to publish my own Web Module so I make a empty path with docBase.

But automatically added path "/" conflict with this path.

Comment: Could you please explain the steps and what you are looking to achieve. It would help to understand the problem better.

Comment: I want to deploy to my own path ""(whitespace). But STS deploy to path "/". I assume Web Setting context path set "/" so it automatically deploy to there. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I found STS deploy to '.metadata\...' and use that path. I want to deploy my own Context Docbase="D:\..." path="" to tomcat server.